# What is the proper way to store a String array in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset

I have a function which selects data from the database and then tries to store it in an ArrayList. 
I want to store each individual columns in a ResultSet in a String array first, and then add the array in the ArrayList.

```
    public void buildConnection() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
    Statement statement =connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from details");
    ResultSetMetaData rSetMd=rSet.getMetaData();
    int ColumnsNo=rSetMd.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<String[]> arrMatrix=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    int j=0;
    while(rSet.next()){
        String arrRows[] = new String[ColumnsNo];
        for(int i=1;i<=ColumnsNo;i++){
            arrRows[i-1]=rSet.getString(i);
        }
        arrMatrix.add(j,arrRows);
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(arrMatrix.get(0)[0]+" "+arrMatrix.get(0)[1]+" "+arrMatrix.get(0)[2]);
    System.out.println(arrMatrix.get(1)[0]+" "+arrMatrix.get(1)[1]+" "+arrMatrix.get(1)[2]);

}
```

The problem is that only the last entry from the database shows up in the arraylist. All the other entries are getting lost. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE:
the output:

```
 1 Axel Namek
 1 Axel Namek
```

where in my database this entry is the last one

Comment: have you tried debugging what happens in the loop?

Comment: Just use `arrMatrix.add(arrRows)` and get rid of `j`. While I don't think that's the source of the error, it's unnecessary complexity.

Comment: arrMatrix.add(arrRows) does the same thing.actually this was what i was using previously.then i got that error so i changed it to the above code.but is still is the same.

Comment: can you please post the output you get ? how many rows are in your database? do both lines print the same thing ?

Comment: oopsss i messed up the output its actually a two line output.and no matter how many times i print it its always the same.

Comment: I've tried it on my side. It gives me perfectly fine data. Here are my rows in database `1 prasad kharkar
2 pranil gilda
3 sushant pangarkar` and my output is  `1 prasad kharkar
2 pranil gilda` You need to check your database buddy. You must have all rows same in it.

Comment: yeah actually the problem was probably in the sqlYog installation. re-installing it completely solved that problem. may be installing a windows app in ubuntu through wine has its own consequence.thanks for your time and help bro.much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use;

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` in place of `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Using this method you are then able to;

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrMatrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
arrMatrix.add(new ArrayList<String>());
arrMatrix.get(0).add("string value");
System.out.println(arrMatrix.get(0).get(0));
//string value
```

Though, i suspect this is not what you are after either. a better approach is to create a new class with first and surname fields and referencing those

```
public class Names {
    public String firstname = null;
    public String surname = null;
    public Names(String first, String sur) {
        firstname = first;
        surname = sur;
    }
}
```

from that point on;

```
Names instance = new Names("John", "Doe");
System.out.println(instance.firstname); // John
System.out.println(instance.surname); // Doe
```

It is trivial at the point to create an arraylist of names. Obviously, this example can be build on more.

I question your underlying motives you must be doing something else with the array, or you would just print it in the loop.

Comment: this should be a comment though.

Comment: in that case how can i add elements to the inner ArrayList?